# Finding references of MyClass.toString() in Eclipse while ignoring Object.toString()

Tags: java, eclipse, tostring

When attempting to do so, Eclipse will display all the calls in the project for any `.toString()` method, which is of course not what I'm aiming to.

Is there any way to filter the matches such that only classes of a certain type show up in the results pane?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41733558/2940429) answers the question best.

Answer (score 10):

Either right-click your override toString() method and select *References > Workspace*, or simply press Ctrl+Shift+G while the cursor is on the method.

As some people have pointed out the list of results will normally include the vast number of references to the toString() method of class Object, which can be thousands or tens of thousands of hits. This obviously makes the whole search rather useless.

Luckily you can filter the results, by clicking on the little triangle on the top right of the Search tab and select to filter out all *References to Overridden*, which will leave you with just the references to your concrete class' method override.

Comment: This answers the original question! There are still a couple false positives, but not thousands of them. Do you leave this filter turned on all the time?

Comment: @Noumenon I generally do, but of course it depends on the situation. Sometime you do of course explicitly want to include inherited methods in a search, just probably not for `toString()` and the like. So long as you know the filter setting exists and how it works (namely that a checked filter means inherited/overridden methods will be filtered out and __not__ be visible), it's easy to use whichever way you require, just a few clicks away.

Answer (score 6):

If your class overrides `toString()`, right-click on method name > References > Workspace.

If your class doesn't override `toString()`, you can't.

Implicit calls, for example when instances of your class are concatenated with a `String`, won't ever show.

Comment: I can't find "find usages" in the context menu. Is this in the old version or where can I find it in Keppler?

Comment: @otakun85 Right-click on method name > References > Workspace

Comment: @otakun85 yes - I just tested that and you're correct. I've removed that part from my answer. thx!

Comment: When I do a "find references" on a toString() method I get all calls to toString(), not just ones to the particular class's toString(). You mention, "If your class overrides toString()..." - well, my class **does** override toString() but I can't find **only** the references to my class's toString() method!